# Bot detection without client script

Tags: fraud, bot, cloudflare

I am working in a small startup and we are looking for Security tools - mostly WAF and Bot Detection (specifically to identify click fraud).

Some solutions that integrate client side scripts are ShieldSquare, Distill Networks, Datadome and PerimeterX, but they are priced a little high.
Some solutions that can be used without client side scripts are Cloudflare, Imperva, Fortinet and more, which can also contain in a reasonable price WAF and DDOS protection.

I wanted to know if the quality of a tool that doesn't include client side script is necessarilly worse, since the client side script sends a token which is hard to fraud, or these tools without client side can somehow be smart enough to overcome this obstacle?

Also if there are solutions that identify click fraud that I didn't mention (specificlly in our site, not in Google/Bing ads e.g Clixtell, PPCProtect, Clickcease) or that can include all in the same package,  - I would be happy to hear.